# Unit Testing - Algorithm or Sample based?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, language-agnostic

Say I'm trying to test a simple Set class

```
public IntSet : IEnumerable<int>
{
    Add(int i) {...}
    //IEnumerable implementation...
}
```

And suppose I'm trying to test that no duplicate values can exist in the set. My first option is to insert some sample data into the set, and test for duplicates using my knowledge of the data I used, for example:

```
    //OPTION 1
    void InsertDuplicateValues_OnlyOneInstancePerValueShouldBeInTheSet()
    {
        var set = new IntSet();

        //3 will be added 3 times
        var values = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5};
        foreach (int i in values)
            set.Add(i);

        //I know 3 is the only candidate to appear multiple times
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (int i in set)
            if (i == 3) counter++;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, counter);
    }
```

My second option is to test for my condition generically:

```
    //OPTION 2
    void InsertDuplicateValues_OnlyOneInstancePerValueShouldBeInTheSet()
    {
        var set = new IntSet();

        //The following could even be a list of random numbers with a duplicate
        var values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5};
        foreach (int i in values)
            set.Add(i);

        //I am not using my prior knowledge of the sample data 
        //the following line would work for any data
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new HashSet<int>(values), set);
    }
```

Of course, in this example, I conveniently have a set implementation to check against, as well as code to compare collections (CollectionAssert). But what if I didn't have either ? This code would be definitely more complicated than that of the previous option! And this is the situation when you are testing your real life custom business logic.

Granted, testing for expected conditions generically covers more cases - but it becomes very similar to implementing the logic again (which is both tedious and useless - you can't use the same code to check itself!). Basically I'm asking whether my tests should look like "insert 1, 2, 3 then check something about 3" or "insert 1, 2, 3 and check for something in general"

EDIT - To help me understand, please state in your answer if you prefer OPTION 1 or OPTION 2 (or neither, or that it depends on the case, etc). Just to clarify, it's pretty clear that in *this* case (`IntSet`), option 2 is better in all aspects. However, my question pertains to the cases where you *don't* have an alternative implementation to check against, so the code in option 2 would be definitely more complicated than option 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I'm asking whether my tests
>   should look like "insert 1, 2, 3 then
>   check something about 3" or "insert 1,
>   2, 3 and check for something in
>   general"

I am not a TDD purist but it seems people are saying that the test should break if the condition that you are trying to test is broken. e.i. if you implement a test which checks a general condition, then your test will break in more than a few cases so it is not optimal.

*If I am testing for not being able to add duplicates, then I would only test that.* So in this case, I would say I would go with **first**.

### (Update)

OK, now you have updated the code and I need to update my answer.

Which one would I choose? It depends on the implementation of `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new HashSet<int>(values), set);`. For example, `IEnumerable<T>` does keep the order while `HashSet<T>` does not so even this could break the test while it should not. For me **first** is still superior.

Comment: I disagree: Both of his example code snippets are testing the same constraint (in the sense that they will both fail if the module-under-test breaks in any way).  It's just that the second approach does it in a simpler way (less test code needs to be written).

Comment: Oh this was updated 5 minutes ago and I have not seen that. Let me read again.

Comment: Forget this specific example, I'm talking about the case equivalent to not having `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` at all (meaning you'd have to implement it yourself if you wanted that logic) !

Answer (score 2):

If you have an alternative implementation, then definitely use it.

In some situations, you can avoid reimplementing an alternative implementation, but still test the functionality in general.  For instance, in your example, you could first generate a set of unique values, and then randomly duplicate elements before passing it to your implementation.  You can test that the output is equivalent to your starting vector, without having to reimplement the sort.

I try to take this approach whenever it's feasible.

**Update:** Essentially, I'm advocating the OP's "Option #2".  With this approach, there's precisely one output vector that will allow the test to pass.  With "Option #1", there's an infinite number of acceptable output vectors (it's testing an invariant, but it's not testing for any relationship to the input data).

Comment: True (+1), but in RL you won't have the code equivalent to the one that compares the collections (CollectionAssert). Writing that code is almost like writing the `Set` again (though you could do it less efficiently, of course)

Comment: @ohadsc: Really?  That particular function is just a simple comparison-based test.  (a) Why would you not have access to it?  (b) Even if you didn't, it would be trivial to write a method to compare two vectors.

Comment: Perhaps I've misspoken - forget the set. My point is that in RL cases you won't have the *equivalent* code to the one comparing the collections - which is part of the code that checks your condition.

Comment: @ohadsc: Oh, I see!  However, writing a test always involves writing some sort of pass/fail code...

Comment: True, but the question is how is "smart" that pass/fail code? is it smart enough to work only with the data you've inserted, possibly checking only part of it yet staying simple - or is it generic in the sense that it would work for any data, and probably cover more cases (at the expense of being more complicated) ?

Comment: @ohadsc: I take your point.  You're right, it's not always trivial to write generic pass/fail code.  But hopefully in many cases, you should be able to construct a test that boils down to some sort of straightforward "does this match that?".

Comment: @Oli - I think that's exactly option 1, in my terminology ?

Comment: @ohadsc: No, I'm advocating Option #2 whenever it's possible.  With Option #1, there's an infinite number of output vectors that would pass the test.  With Option #2, there's precisely one way for the test to pass.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to test use cases one by one - this works nicely the TDD manner: "code a little, test a little". Of course, after a while my test cases start to contain duplicated code, so I refactor. The actual method of verifying the results does not matter to me as long as it is working for sure, and doesn't get into the way of testing itself. So if there is a "reference implementation" to test against, it is all the better.

An important thing, however, is that the **tests should be reproducable** and **it should be clear what each test method is actually testing**. To me, inserting random values into a collection is neither - of course if there is a *huge* amount of data/use cases involved, every tool or approach is welcome which helps to handle the situation better without lulling me into a false sense of security.

Comment: So you're saying - go for option 2 when easy / convenient, but option 1 would do as well ?

Comment: @ohadsc, basically yes. In my unit tests this check would be extracted into a helper method anyway, so I wouldn't be bothered much by the difference :-)

Comment: @Péter Török - When you say "this check" do you mean `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new HashSet<int>(values), set)` ?

Comment: @ohadsc, either that or your variant 1. I mean, the actual implementation of the helper method would be, well, an implementation detail :-)

Comment: Right :) however, my point is that in many cases of option 2, the implementation of that helper method would have to be very similar to the logic of the code being tested. For example, say you have a function that gets a tree and returns its leafs - how would you check it generally without comparing against another implementation of a function that does the same thing ?

Comment: @ohadsc, as long as I have a reference implementation which is proven to be correct, I don't care about its implementation details *while unit testing*. Of course, it may be interesting and important to see the state of the art *when writing my own implementation*.

Comment: @ Péter Török - my question is precisely what do you do when you *don't* have a reference operation ?

Comment: @ohadsc, sorry, I misunderstood you. OK, when there is no reference implementation, there should still be some sort of specification. So I write the simplest code which can verify that a given part of the specification is fulfilled. As I add more test cases, the verification code may need to be refactored/extended to handle more general needs. And I strive to test the testing code itself as well, by intentionally "breaking" my tests and verifying that they indeed fail when they are supposed to.

Comment: "So I write the simplest code which can verify that a given part of the specification is fulfilled" - so you'd choose between option 1 and 2 based on what's simpler ?

Comment: @ohadsc, when I don't have a reference operation, there is no option 2 :-) But in general, yes, I follow the XP/agile principle of selecting the simplest solution which could possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054), it's usually more favorable to test the *state* of the system under test. If you want to test its *behavior* and the way in which the algorithm operates, you can use Mock Object Testing.

That being said, both of your tests are known as Data Driven Tests. What is usually acceptable is to use as much knowledge as the API provides. Remember, those tests also serve as documentation for your software. Therefore it's critical to keep them as simple as possible - whatever that means for your specific case.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test whether the set now has duplicates or not - that's state. My question remains - should I opt for the first option, or the second?

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be demonstrating the correctness of the Add method using an activity diagram/flowchart.  The next step would be to formally prove the correctness of the Add method if you have the time. Then testing with a specific sets of data where you expect duplications and non-duplications (i.e. some sets of data have duplications and some sets don't and you are seeing if the data structure performs correctly - it's important to have cases that should succeed (no duplicates) and to check that they were added correctly to the set rather than just testing for failure cases (cases in which duplicates should be found)).  And finally checking generically.  Even though it is now somewhat deprecated I would suggest constructing data to fully exercise every execution path in the method being tested.  At any point you made a code change then begin all over applying regression testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the algorithmic approach, but preferably without relying on an alternate implementation such as HashSet.  You're actually testing for more than just "no duplicates" with the HashSet match.  For example, the test will fail if any items didn't make it into the resulting set, and you presumably have other tests that check for this.

A cleaner verification of the "no duplicates" expectation might be something like the following:

```
Assert.AreEqual(values.Distinct().Count(), set.Count());
```

Comment: I actually have no problem with my tests checking for more than one thing at a time, as long as what I'm interested in is one of them. Why would you not use an alternate implementation, though ?